# Flatness of a subring generated by two subrings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $S$ be a commutative $\mathbb{C}$-algebra and let $a,b,c,d \in S$.
Assume that $R_1:=\mathbb{C}[a+c,b+d] \subseteq S$ is flat and
$R_1:=\mathbb{C}[a-c,b-d] \subseteq S$ is flat.

> **Question 1:** Is it true that $\mathbb{C}[a,b,c,d] \subseteq S$ is flat?

More generally, if $A_1,A_2 \subseteq B$ are two subrings of $B$ (sub $\mathbb{C}$-algebras of the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra $B$) such that $A_i \subseteq B$ is flat, $1 \leq i \leq 2$,

> **Question 2:** Is it true that $B$ is flat over $A$, where $A$ is the $\mathbb{C}$-algebra generated by $A_1,A_2$?

Non-counterexample: $A_1=\mathbb{C}[x], A_2=\mathbb{C}[y], B=\mathbb{C}[x,y,z]$; all the relevant extensions are free, hence flat.

Counterexample: $A_1=\mathbb{C}[x^2], A_2=\mathbb{C}[x^3], B=\mathbb{C}[x]$: Here $A_i \subseteq B$ are free (hence flat), but $A=\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3] \subseteq B$ is not flat. (If we change the first question to $R_1=\mathbb{C}[a], R_2=\mathbb{C}[b]$, then the ring generated by $R_1$ and $R_2$ is $\mathbb{C}[a,b]$ and $\mathbb{C}[a,b] \subseteq S$ is not flat for $a=x^2, b=x^3, S=\mathbb{C}[x]$).

> **Question 3:** Is it possible to find a mild condition which will guarantee  positive answers to my questions?

The condition: $R_i \subseteq S$ are *integral ring extensions* will not help, as the above counterexample shows.

What about a condition involving *fields of fractions*?

What about a condition saying: $A_i \subseteq B$ is a *separable* (or even *etale*) *ring extension*?

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329469/when-flatness-of-b-over-a-implies-flatness-of-b-over-c-where-a-subset) is a slightly more general question, with no answers.
[This](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/51095/flat-module-and-torsion-free-module?rq=1) question is relevant (especially, if we further assume that $S$ and $B$ are *integral domains*).
[Tensor products](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/128217/flatness-and-tensor-product-of-rings) and [products of rings](https://pdf.sciencedirectassets.com/272332/1-s2.0-S0021869300X03651/1-s2.0-0021869382900126/main.pdf?X-Amz-Security-Token=IQoJb3JpZ2luX2VjEMH%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2F%2FwEaCXVzLWVhc3QtMSJIMEYCIQCJ29S4TnaGtZDSleyS4hFw5D45GWa%2FNMwSfYfNENgJYwIhAMho1xD%2FI8rt7HmJMa4v%2FzJToo5gesme0mgDZWV8gq8oKrQDCGoQAxoMMDU5MDAzNTQ2ODY1Igztr1j%2F16LiODIK1IoqkQN12BWinx%2FRd3VGpVK91ZwznPvnTJz1k1g9KdEr9j9Q86HqqRpxZlmXrcEnVrbKhKIVq0sCpb6wRRqP630ql9hzh1SNwkE7nvoYH4uFOhS2wPL8RnSZlCPLKzGo3QmHaYgkA2WPusiFQpELpHqNlKGDQeBmy4j%2B4Yx5XVE4myIjNmIyoDsvdDBXPNOqkeQADiOTRaQYq1mjLjY9JCqXvyIDr9vujeoEW%2F9uIlfL14MuSNd1sf0IIDeqmhsLTg1XywedDEveBHvlhivU%2FUgy%2BNLbzSwaJE3NDr2fU1hSWZuFDLJ%2BK7qJ0f3B9o%2F4aj8L87CEHLpyugmo%2BkAUcwltwc7TncviUc3wOTSew9wSj1hyO3bIzwm6XvEdDtWtXnyuYrUrsVu%2BN2zEHM1%2BrtLFQ6vp69C8%2BuO5MzsEMCDxrubzme8mNq9O30SFO4wsEqiotwrWwTxr45%2FgmNZcr74BUZzUyY6Dp0GGolItuoA28ol8wTO576NrHpiX5%2F1835OeguU5CjnnzNo1BhtGDNmLqd0iuzDfvPr%2BBTrqAZA2OOeoZ9KU7%2B3m7ilFlG7fbAUDSov%2BVGqX1DN1dMvpDByQI2ZOdmwU1N%2F%2FponapT%2FW1BURQj3EZUV%2FZGkJQ%2BuZg%2BIhEeatn2f8IbvyRmf2vwcqO3tcr6tJwYDJfMO1SIA6p01D%2F298QKO9KIiwiG7ZZrNQDD9CTnC%2B2OdYHa6XCSZfJlM1RxUJ7bLJnM7QyQONvlu95KJiggM3A6H%2BM%2B8b7hbdG3tJYS4AZeJY5uJoQQ1UEAdaaKrlPjMcSu9DuzYEJLDz%2FYWmz2SFHEplgCmDJsNiDclVFa16yvcjP5Yy%2FlfqQHn0iXkfqA%3D%3D&X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20201220T022614Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=300&X-Amz-Credential=ASIAQ3PHCVTYR7AST6FI%2F20201220%2Fus-east-1%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=4d037c8cb8aab2a57d8534eaf602327eebad1e23cce993f2fe61cc086ec35481&hash=c9f5fdae3dfde8df873d61dd4dd1752c679ffe59f5b228adafea3886c0a898fa&host=68042c943591013ac2b2430a89b270f6af2c76d8dfd086a07176afe7c76c2c61&pii=0021869382900126&tid=spdf-d5309ac3-567b-4a79-b9e3-e42912091d49&sid=fb1c3e64311bc847b15961445d6e53d411a5gxrqb&type=client) (probably less relevant).

Now also asked in [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/379369/flatness-of-certain-subrings).

Thank you very much!

Comment: I'm not sure how to go about this, but I think the notion of a [linearly disjoint extension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linearly_disjoint) could be helpful. This says that the tensor product of these algebras over $\mathbb C$ is the generated algebra.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop, thank you for the comment, sounds interesting. Could you please elaborate your idea?

Comment: I'm afraid it's not a very specific approach I have in mind. It just seems to me that flatness would be easier to approach using a tensor product rather than a compositum, so considering when they are the same could be helpful.

Comment: @paulblartmathcop, thank you for elaborating your idea. I will try to think about it. Any further comments are welcome!