# Flatness of $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ over $\mathbb{C}[f]$, $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $n \geq 1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, commutative-algebra, free-modules, flatness

Let $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $n \geq 1$.
Call $f$ 'good' if $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is flat over $\mathbb{C}[f]$.

> Is it true that every $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is good?

- $f \in \mathbb{C}$ is good, since $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is free (hence flat) over $\mathbb{C}$.
- $n=1$: $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is a free $\mathbb{C}[x^2]$-module (of rank two), hence flat, so $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is flat over $\mathbb{C}[x^2]$. Similarly, if $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ is of degree $d$, then $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is free (hence flat) over $\mathbb{C}[f]$ of rank $d$.
  Therefore, every $f$ is good.
- $n=2$: If $f \in \mathbb{C}[x]$ then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is free (of infinite rank) over $\mathbb{C}[f]$ and if $f \in \mathbb{C}[y]$ then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is free (of infinite rank) over $\mathbb{C}[f]$.
  But what about a general $f \in \mathbb{C}[x,y]$? It seems to me that the extension is still free: If $\deg_x(f)=d_1 < \infty$ and $\deg_y(f)=d_2 < \infty$, then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is free of rank $d_1d_2$. If $\deg_x(f) = -\infty$ or $\deg_y(f) = -\infty$, then $\mathbb{C}[x,y]$ is free of infinite rank.
- $n \geq 3$, similarly to the $n=2$ case, every $f$ is good.

Summarizing, it seems that $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is free (hence flat) over $\mathbb{C}[f]$, for every $f \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$.

Please, am I right or wrong?
Thank you very much.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, thank you very much for your two comments! (1) Nice, ok. (2) This sounds very interesting, however much more difficult.. I will search MO. Thanks!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez, even for $n=1$, $\mathbb{C}[x]$ is not flat over $\mathbb{C}[x^2,x^3]$, so it is not easy to determine what $f$ and $g$ should be...(I think I once asked this question here). For $n \geq 2$ this seems much more difficult to me, though very interesting.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3955627/flatness-of-a-subring-generated-by-two-subrings

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/04PQ This might be a helpful

Comment: @CoherentSheaf, thank you very much for the link! Seems relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an algebraic-geometric way to prove this, though it might be considered cracking a nut with a sledgehammer. For non-constant $f$, the inclusion $\mathbb C[f] \subset \mathbb C[x_1, \dotsc, x_n]$ induces a morphism of schemes
$$f: \mathbb A^n \to \mathbb A^1, \quad (p_1, \dotsc, p_n) \mapsto f(p_1, \dotsc, p_n).$$
Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry*, Chapter III.9 contains the following

> **Proposition 9.7.** *Let $f: X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes with $Y$ integral and regular of dimension $1$. Then $f$ is flat if and only if every associated point $x \in X$ maps to the generic point of $Y$. In particular, if $X$ is reduced, this say that every irreducible component of $X$ dominates $Y$.*

As $\mathbb A^n$ is reduced with a single irreducible component, we see that the morphism $f$ is flat because $f$ is non-constant.

Comment: Thank you very much! Indeed, I was also interested in an algebraic-geometric proof. Please, is a similar argument can solve the more general problem mentioned by Mariano Suárez-Álvarez, namely, for which algebraically independent $f,g \in \mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$, $\mathbb{C}[x_1,\ldots,x_n]$ is flat over $\mathbb{C}[f,g]$? (Adding the condition 'algebraically independent' excludes several known non-flat cases such as $f=x^2, g=x^3$).