# Flatness of $R+I \subseteq S$, where $R \subseteq S$ is flat

Tags: algebraic-geometry, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, flatness

Given $A \subseteq C \subseteq B$ with $A \subseteq B$ flat,
when $C \subseteq B$ is flat?
This question appears [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329469/when-flatness-of-b-over-a-implies-flatness-of-b-over-c-where-a-subset).

Now, I wonder if restricting the above question to to following special case would be easier to answer:

Let $R \subseteq S$ be two (commutative) integral domains,
$I$ an ideal of $S$. Obviously, $R+I$ is a ring.
We have, $R \subseteq R+I \subseteq S$.
Assume that $R \subseteq S$ is flat.

> **Question:** When $R+I \subseteq S$ is flat?

One plausible positive answer to this question is when all those three rings
have the same field of fractions, see Richman [Lemma 2(1), page 795](https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1965-016-04/S0002-9939-1965-0181653-1/S0002-9939-1965-0181653-1.pdf).

**Motivation:** The following is a known result: Given $A \subseteq C \subseteq B$ with $A \subseteq B$ [separable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separable_algebra), implies that $C \subseteq B$ is separable.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Why is $R+I$ flat over $R$?

Comment: Thank you for the comment. I have seen this claim (that $R \subseteq R+I$ is flat) in one of MSE's questions, and truly, have not checked this myself, though I should have. Perhaps I should delete this. Please notice that in Richman's result for $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$, it is not assumed that $A \subseteq B$ is flat.

Comment: Please, any ideas when flatness of $R \subseteq S$ implies flatness of $R+I \subseteq S$ are welcome.

Comment: Perhaps flatness of $R \subseteq R+I$ (if this claim is true), follows from $\frac{R}{R \cap I}=\frac{R+I}{I}$.

Comment: I think in Richman's result we can weaken the hypotheses substantially... Something like $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are arbitrary rings such that $A \subseteq C$ is flat and there exists a ring $D$ containing $C$ such that $A \subseteq D$ is an epimorphism of rings.  What's the motivation for your question? Where does the ring $R+ I$ come up in practice? Can you link to the question claiming that $R + I$ is flat over $R$?

Comment: @BadamBaplan, thank you for your comment. (1) Please, could you make your idea into an answer? It sounds very interesting, though I do not know why your claim is true. (2) My motivation is to understand the following problem: Given $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ with $A \subseteq C$ flat, when (i) $A \subseteq B$ is flat and (ii) $B \subseteq C$ is flat. I once thought that (i) always holds, but I think I was wrong. I compare this to the result that $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ with $A \subseteq C$ is separable implies that $B \subseteq C$ is separable. (3) I will try to find the link soon.

Comment: Ok, that's good to know. Your comment articulates a  good question about flatness that people might actually show interest in but your post as is doesn't reflect it. I would suggest editing / retitling or just asking a new question.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, thank you. Actually, I have asked (ii) here (a lnog time ago) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1329469/when-flatness-of-b-over-a-implies-flatness-of-b-over-c-where-a-subset, but have not received an answer. Now I thought/hoped that restricting to a specific intermediate ring would somehow help. Ok, I will soon edit the above post.

Comment: Ah yes it's always a good idea to link to related questions.

Comment: @BadamBaplan, please could you elaborate your idea: "I think in Richman's result we can weaken the hypotheses substantially... Something like $A \subseteq B \subseteq C$ are arbitrary rings such that $A \subseteq C$ is flat and there exists a ring $D$ containing $C$ such that $A \subseteq D$ is an epimorphism of rings.", perhaps in an answer?